# Get element values in xsl:variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, xsl-variable

Please forgive my ignorance of XSLT I'm fairly new to it.

Using saxon xslt 2.0: I'm trying to get a single element from an xsl:variable that looks like this when applying `<xsl:copy-of select="$type">`:

```
  <type>
     <label>Book</label>
     <id>book</id>
  </type>
```

Trying to access the id element only - I've attempted:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$type/id">
<xsl:copy-of select="$type[2]">
<xsl:value-of select="$type/id">
<xsl:value-of select="$type[2]">
```

Also tried this and a few variants as well

```
<xsl:value-of select="$type[name()='id']"/>
```

And tried changing the data type

```
<xsl:variable name="type" as="element">
```

With XSLT 2.0 node-set() manipulations don't seem to apply.

I seek a detailed description of how to properly access xsl:variable elements and would also be happy to find I'm using this all wrong there's a better way. Thank you for your insights and efforts.

@martin-honnen
When adding:

```
<xsl:variable name="test1">
  <type>
     <label>Book</label>
     <id>book</id>
  </type>
</xsl:variable>

<TEST1><xsl:copy-of select="$test1/type/id"/></TEST1>

<xsl:variable name="test2" as="element()">
  <type>
     <label>Book</label>
     <id>book</id>
  </type>
</xsl:variable>

<TEST2><xsl:copy-of select="$test2/id"/></TEST2>
```

I get the result:

```
   <TEST1/>
   <TEST2/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
<xsl:variable name="type">
  <type>
     <label>Book</label>
     <id>book</id>
  </type>
</xsl:variable>
```

then you need e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="$type/type/id"/>` to copy the `id` element as the `type` variable is bound to a temporary document node containing a `type` element node with an `id` child element node.

Or use

```
<xsl:variable name="type" as="element()">
  <type>
     <label>Book</label>
     <id>book</id>
  </type>
</xsl:variable>
```

then `<xsl:copy-of select="$type/id"/>` works, as now the variable is bound to the `type` element node.

Here is a complete sample with my suggestions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:variable name="test1">
  <type>
     <label>Book</label>
     <id>book</id>
  </type>
</xsl:variable>

<TEST1><xsl:copy-of select="$test1/type/id"/></TEST1>

<xsl:variable name="test2" as="element()">
  <type>
     <label>Book</label>
     <id>book</id>
  </type>
</xsl:variable>

<TEST2><xsl:copy-of select="$test2/id"/></TEST2>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output is

```
<TEST1>
   <id>book</id>
</TEST1>
<TEST2>
   <id>book</id>
</TEST2>
```

Comment: Well for the first sample you have not followed my suggestion. The second should work and does for me, I have edited my answer with a complete sample showing both ways and the output I get with Saxon 9. If you still have problems then post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I've updated the above and accepted answer as it should work this way as you've shown.

Comment: My complete sample should work. If your paths don't select anything then probably because your stylesheet has `xmlns="..."`. You could use `<xsl:variable name="test" xmlns=""><type><id>1</id></type></xsl:variable>` to make sure the elements in the variable are in no namespace.

Comment: Thank you - it looks like a namespace issue. I'll accept as answer once I've got 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

To access a element value, just specify XPath correctly that is `type/id`

```
<xsl:value-of select="type/id" />
```